# git updated filestructure not deleting filestructure from previous commit

Tags: git

I have a remote repo with the following filesystem from commit 1:

```
dir1____file1
   |____file2
   |____file3
dir2____subdir1____file4
   |          |____file5
   |____subdir2
```

I cloned it into my local repo and changed the filestructure by moving some files and deleting previous folders and creating some new ones, in commit 2 to the following:

```
dirname1____file1
dirname2____file2
dirname3____file3
dirnameB____subdirname1____file4
                      |____file5
dirnameC____file6
```

After I pushed this commit to the remote repo, I expect the main branch (note that I am not working on any branches) to have the updated filestructure from commit 2, but what the remote repo is showing is the combination of both, thus causing redundancy:

```
dir1____file1
   |____file2
   |____file3
dir2____subdir1____file4
   |          |____file5
   |____subdir2  
dirname1____file1
dirname2____file2
dirname3____file3
dirnameB____subdirname1____file4
                      |____file5
dirnameC____file6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have github and gitlab as tags. Pick one or the other; they're different.

Comment: @torek Done! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What does git status say?

Comment: What commands did you execute? Did you remove the old paths?

Answer (score 0):

I got what was wrong. The unwanted directories needed to be deleted with "git rm" instead of "rm". Even the deletions needed to be staged.

Comment: `rm` works, just don't forget to `git add -A . && git commit`